# Oracle 00904 error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting this error when trying to upload this script to Oracle. Does it have to do with my insert commands?

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY';
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE( 
EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER (15) PRIMARY KEY,
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('1001', 'JOHN', 'SMITHSON');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('1002', 'WILL', 'SMITH');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('1003', 'JASON', 'BOURNE');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('1004', 'RANDY', 'MARSH');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('1005', 'ANGELA', 'CARTMAN');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('1006', 'JANE', 'DOE');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('1007', 'MARY', 'JONES');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a extra , at the end of create table

```
LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,   -- remove ,
);
```

the varchar to number conversion works but better to give data in number for the first column

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be putting apostrophes around your numbers. Try it without them.